# Disable EE2 cookies

Tags: ee2, cookies

I've like to disable as many cookies as I can for the default EE2 install. The following cookies are being set but with the new GDPR laws I don't want to have to list this in the cookies page so I would just rather turn them off for everyone.

These are the default cookies set. I can't see a way to disable them.

__csrf_token

__last_activity

__last_visit

__tracker

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible if you put your admin.php file in a subfolder and use a cookie path that is equal to the name of the subfolder.**

Cookies will then only be set for the CP and you still will be able to login.

--

Let's say you name the cp-folder "maskedcp" and you put your admin.php file in that folder. Then you have to edit the index.php and admin.php.

After that navigate to Admin -> Security & Privacy -> Cookie Settings

Set the cookie path field to "/maskedcp" (without the quotes)

Comment: The aforementioned cookies will still be set for any anyonymous website visitor. 
Personally I found no other simple way than hacking the core to stop that.

Comment: @user1013 Which core files did you hack or how did you go about find the locations to hack?

Comment: /system/expressionengine/libraries/Session.php
/system/expressionengine/libraries/csrf/Cookie.php

Comment: Look for:
ee()->input->set_cookie

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding cookies that are essential to website operation are NOT covered under the GDPR. It's only if you are using it for analytics is there an issue.

The 'exp_tracker' cookie for example is needed to return a user to the previous page (or 2) by EE in some instances. As long as you have all the tracking items turned off in EE even that cookie is considered essential.

EE cookies aren't really your issue under the GDPR, analytics, media embeds, adverts... (3rd party stuff) are the issues to deal with.